# Mat-tab content body lazy load not displaying

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Im trying to write a tab with a lazy loading content body by following the api and example **[here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading)** but it doesn't work.

```
  <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
      Content 1
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
      <!-- This must be lazily load -->
      <ng-template matTabContent>
        Content 2
      </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

Can anyone care to explain why this thing is not working?

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tab-lazy-load-issue)**

Comment: Try version 6.0.0. See also https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/6feaf62585be9b6d9eee2440eb7b5fe5dcb498c5#diff-9c1b1226b191d3f83a5a2ab43d2682fe

Comment: oh so this one just recently released? my bad

Comment: Yeah, it's new feature

Comment: lot of thanks then!

Comment: Now working, but not with nested tabs!!!!